# pm2 does not restart worker when express error occur

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, uncaught-exception, pm2

I'm using pm2 to manage process in my nodejs express application (running in cluster mode).

We had 2 kind of error handler

- FIRST: 'uncaughtException' will be handled with

  ```
  process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){});
  ```

Actually, I do not declare an handler like this cause of letting pm2 detect died worker in this case so restart the died worker automatically.

- SECOND: express error handler, I mean the error will be forwarded to express error handler, not uncaughtException handler, the error handler like below

  ```
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {})
  ```

I also do not declare this error handler for same purpose as uncaughtException.
But pm2 does not restart node in this case.

Any idea about this problem?
Many thanks

Comment: Is there actually a need for your app to be restarted? If I'm not mistaken the app is still running and can respond to new requests. Since the exception was caught you should respond in express error handler with some nice page saying that there was a problem instead of letting client's browser to timeout.

Comment: Yes, when error is caught by express error handlers, the server won't be crashed. But, exception means there's some problems in your code, and maybe server will come into unstable state and you can not know what it may react to request in future. I think in that case, we should restart this node.

Comment: Then you can try process.exit(0) in error handler after you log what happened. pm2 should restart it.

Comment: Yeah, i've just do that and everything is ok now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When catching errors with express error handler or even "uncaughtException" event, the process is still running, so pm2 won`t restart it.
If you want pm2 to restart after each exception, I would suggest something like this:

```
    process.on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
      console.log('An error has occured. error is: %s and stack trace is: %s', e, e.stack);
      console.log("Process will restart now.");
      process.exit(1);
    })
```

Same goes for the express error handler. When we execute process.exit method, the process will terminate and pm2 will restart it.